# Connection to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx was closed Ubuntu 11.10 to Mac

Tags: 11.10, remote-desktop

I am trying to do a remote desktop connection to a Mac using the remote desktop viewer in Ubuntu 11.10 with the VCN protocol. I get to the password prompt enter my password then I get the error that the connection was closed. I can SSH to the Mac and navigate via the command line with no problem, but I really need to access the desktop. I would appreciate any suggestions as I am at a loss. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you setup up the Mac to be Accessed Remotely?

Comment: yes my adviser set the mac up for remote access and he can access it form his personal mac which is why I think the problem lies with Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you can ssh to the mac, you should tunnel the VNC connection over ssh. Check the box in vinagre that says:

```
Use host (blank) as a SSH tunnel
```

and fill in the blank with the hostname for the mac.

Comment: I tried using the host name and got this error `Timed out when logging in`

Comment: To be clear, you are using the same thing for both boxes.  From your question title, I would assume that you entered in an IP address into the first box.  Did you enter the same thing into the second box?

Comment: good call. I copied the host address wrong in the  second box. I did it again, got to the password prompt then Connection to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XX was closed error again.

Comment: I think you'll need to figure out where the log files are for vinagre and look at those, possibly increasing the verbosity.  If vinagre doesn't have such an option, try a different vnc viewer such as xtightvncviewer or xvnc4viewer. It will certainly be difficult to diagnose the problem from such a vague message.